# Process items in Uni<List> asynchronously

Tags: java, reactive-programming, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I have a Uni

```
Uni<List<String>> list = Uni.createFrom().item(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
```

I would like to map each item in this list to a new Uni and then process them asynchronously.

I have tried following:

```java
list.map(strings -> strings.stream().map(this::processItem).toList())
                .flatMap(unis -> Uni.join().all(unis).andCollectFailures())
                .subscribe()
                .with(System.out::println);

    private Future<String> process(String s) {
        return executor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("start " + s);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("end " + s);
            return s;
        });
    }

    private Uni<Void> processItem(String item) {
        return Uni.createFrom().future(process(item))
                .replaceWithVoid();
    }
```

However, this only processes the first element of the list. How can I map a Uni to a List and process each Uni asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.subscribe().with(System.out::println);` is asynchronous, if you don't add some check to make sure that the stream is over, the program will exit before the first result is available.

I usually work with [Vert.x unit](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_junit_integration):

```java
    @Test
    public void test(TestContext context) {
        Random random = new Random();
        // This is only used to signal the test
        // when the stream is terminated
        Async async = context.async();

        Uni.createFrom()
                .item( List.of( "a", "b", "c" ) )
                // Convert the Uni<List<String>> into a Multi<String>
                .onItem().transformToMulti( Multi.createFrom()::iterable )
                .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge( s ->
                          // You can create a uni the way you prefer
                          Uni.createFrom().item( s )
                                  // Add some random duration
                                  .onItem().delayIt().by( Duration.ofMillis( (random.nextInt(5) + 1) * 1000 ) )
                )
                // End the test only when the stream has terminated
                .onTermination().invoke( (throwable, aBoolean) -> {
                    if (throwable != null ) {
                        context.fail(throwable);
                    }
                    else {
                        async.complete();
                    }
                } )
                .subscribe()
                .with( s -> System.out.println("Printing: " + s) );
    }
```

a while-loop should work as well.

Or, you could collect the results:

```
        Random random = new Random();
        Uni.createFrom()
                .item( List.of( "a", "b", "c" ) )
                // Convert the Uni<List<String>> into a Multi<String>
                .onItem().transformToMulti( Multi.createFrom()::iterable )
                .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge( s -> {
                          final int duration = (random.nextInt( 5 ) + 1) * 1000;
                          // You can create a uni the way you prefer
                          return Uni.createFrom().item( s )
                                  // Add some random duration
                                  .onItem().delayIt().by( Duration.ofMillis( duration ) )
                                  .invoke( () -> System.out.println("Letter: " + s + ", duration in ms: " + duration) );
                } )
                .onItem().invoke( s -> System.out.println("Printing: " + s) )
                .collect().asList().await().indefinitely();
```

Comment: `.transformToUniAndMerge(this::processItem)` When I add this only the first element is processed and I never get the "end" output. FYI. I am using a Java Process to call a native executable in `processItem`

Comment: Are you waiting for the termination of the whole stream? I will update the testcase

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, you need to make sure the app is not exiting until the stream has terminated.

Comment: I've added an example that actually collect the results and doesn't require additional libraries